# Store fetched data from API in a variable and use it for the rest of the code

Tags: javascript

I want to fetch the data set from an external source using **fetch** and then assign the returned value to a variable so that I can access the stored array data throughout my code.
This is the [URL](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/freeCodeCamp/ProjectReferenceData/master/GDP-data.json) from which the data should be retrieved and the following comes with the code snippet where I run into trouble.

```
 const dataset=async function getData(){ 
 const response =await fetch("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/freeCodeCamp/ProjectReferenceData/master/GDP-data.json")
 const parsedData=await response.json()
 const result=await parsedData.data
 return result
}
console.log(dataset())
```

This function is invoked after the execution of fetch and what returns is a promise via which I still couldn't access the array data. Is it the right approach to store the fetched data from external source to a variable and use it afterwards?(the array of data points fetched should be later used for creating bar chart via d3.library)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While `await` looks synchronous all it does is allow the promise (a promise that data will or not be delivered *in the future*) to resolve or reject. So you can't immediately assign a variable to data that doesn't exist yet.

The JS event loop is basically a queuing system. Things go in, and some events get resolved immediately and removed from the queue (mouse events, for example), but promises take time, but when they're complete *then* they get removed from the queue. But while that's happening other events are popped off, so events don't stop happening.

So, while you're still learning about how [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) work, maybe set up a control function that awaits the data and then runs a new function that creates the chart with that data.

```js
const data = '["data"]';

function mockApi() {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    setTimeout(() => res(data), 1000)
  });
}

async function main() {
  const data = await mockApi()
  showData(JSON.parse(data));
}

function showData(data) {
  console.log(data);
}

main();
```